# Parametrization of a line to solve path integrals

Tags: integration, analysis, line-integrals

We have to find the path integral of the following vector along the given curve

$F(x,y,z)=(x^2,z,y)$  along the curve $\gamma$ that parameterizes the line

{$L={(x,y,z) \in R^3: x^2+y^2=1, z=2y+1,x\geq 0}$}
so that its projection on the z = 0 plane is counterclockwise oriented.

I found this in the solved exercise session in my university practice session and the professor immediately says that the parametrization of the line $L$ is:

$\gamma(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t),\sin(t)+1), t\in[-\frac {\pi} 2,\frac \pi 2]$

If possible can you help me understand HOW he parametrized the line L?

I know the rest of the way is just using the formula $\int ^{2\pi}_0F(\gamma(t)\gamma'(t)dt)$ and from here on is easy . But im more interested on how he parametrized the line

Comment: I think there maybe a typo, either z = y+1, or z_gamma = 2 sin t + 1 ...

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal yeah i made a mistake it was supposed to be $x\geq 0$ in the L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^2+y^2=1$ is a unit circle. It can be parameterized as $(x,y) = (\cos(t),\sin(t)),t = [-\pi,\pi]$. This is counter clockwise.

$z = 2y+1$ so $z = 2\sin(t)+1$.

$\gamma(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t),2\sin(t)+1)$

$x \ge 0$ occurs when $\cos(t) \ge 0$, $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks! One more question if possible in the case that the circle has radius of $n^2$ how will the parametrization change?

Comment: If the equation is $x^2 + y^2 = n^2$ then the radius is $n$. The parameters are $(x,y,z) = (n\cos(t),n\sin(t),2n\sin(t)+1)$.

Comment: $x \ge 0$ is still $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: thanks ! This helped quite a lot

Comment: You are welcome.